# How to create DocumentSet in SandBoxed Solution?

Tags: sandbox-solution, document-set

Unfortunately method DocumentSet.Create is not allowed in Sandbox.
Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a trick to create Document Set in a Sandbox Solution.
First Create a Folder and then Convert the Folder to Document Set Content Type. Please check my post below:

http://johnjayaseelan.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/create-document-set-in-sharepoint-2010.html